# Does Chocolatey has “brew tap” equivalent?

Tags: windows, windows-10, package-management, chocolatey

I was wondering if chocolatey package manager has something equivalent to brew tap? In the sense that as a developer I can host some template file(formula) on GitHub and add it to my chocolatey CLI same I do with "tap".

Thanks